# Complicated query with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, join

I have a complicated query that I just cant create. I'm thinking of doing it with JOIN's but don't know where to start. I'll just try to explain my problem as clearly as possible.

I am creating software that deals with compensations. Every compensation can have several links (like in a chain). Each link is basically a customer. So, I'll just tell you the table structures:

Customer

```
CustomerID | Name
```

Compensation

```
CompensationID | CustomerID | Date
```

Link

```
LinkID | CompensationID | CustomerID | Sequential
```

Now, the Sequential field increases with every link added. Let me demonstrate by filling the tables with some data:

```
CustomerID | Name
-----------+-----
0          | Foo
1          | Bar
2          | Baz

CompensationID | CustomerID | Date
---------------+------------+------
0              | 0          | 2-2-2010
1              | 1          | 2-3-2010


    LinkID | CompensationID | CustomerID | Sequential
    -------+----------------+------------+-----------
  0             0             0           0
  1             0             2           1
  2             0             1           2
```

So no matter what the LinkID/CompensationID/CustomerID the Sequential always goes from 0 to N in the Links table (depending on how many links a compensation has).

Now here is the problem: I want to list all Compensation's whose Link's meet the following requirements:

Search in Links
CustomerID = A
Sequential = 0 (first link) AND Sequential = LAST (in this case 2)
List compensations

Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM Compensation JOIN Link ON Compensation.ID = Link.CompensationID
WHERE Link.CustomerID=A AND Link.Sequential = 0 AND Link.Sequential=LAST
```

This is more or less pseudo SQL since I know Link.Sequential cant be 0 and another value at the same time, but I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

P.S.
Sorry for the big wall of text.

Comment: Try with `Link.Sequential = 0 OR Link.Sequential=LAST` (AND will only evaluate when 0 is the LAST - never if there is more then one row in the link table).

Comment: So you want all the first links and all the last links for a single customer?

Comment: I basically need to check if the first and last rows in link have the CustomerID of A. So I need to check for two rows, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If subqueries in where statements work how I remember:

```
select * 
from 
  Compensation
left join
  Link
on Compensation.CompensationID = Link.CompensationID
where
  Link.CustomerID = :A
  AND (
    Link.Sequential = 0
    OR
    Link.Sequential = (
      select MAX(Sequential) from Link where Link.CustomerID = :A
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Compensation c 
JOIN (select CompensationID, MAX(Sequential) AS LastSeq FROM Link GROUP BY CompensationID) AS LastOnes ON c.ID = LastOnes.CompensationID
JOIN (select CompensationID FROM Link WHERE CustomerID=A AND Sequential=0) AS FirststOnes ON c.ID = FirststOnes.CompensationID
JOIN Link AS l on l.CompensationID=c.CompensationID AND l.CustomerID=A AND l.Sequential=LastOnes.LastSeq
```